# Ruby on Rails using Qr Codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

Does anybody know of any tutorials to create a QR CODE in rails 4.0.2 ruby 1.9.3. I have found a number of qr code gems here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/QR_Codes but there is very little documentation to explain how to use them in a website. I am just looking for a simple example of how to create one and then display it. Thanks for help..

Comment: did u checked this http://rubydoc.info/gems/rqrcode/0.4.2/frames, it's gud enough to start with

Comment: I have used and create a QR code in one application.Do you wants to know how and with which gem ?

Comment: hi GhostRider i saw that gem and when i tried to get example working for me i got error "undefined method `modules' for nil:NilClass" any idea how to fix it??

Comment: what is the code you are trying with

Comment: hi Bharat soni if you could show me how to get qr code working and the gem you used that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rqrcode'
qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new( 'youtube.com', :size => 4, :level => :h )
p qr.to_s
```

This code works for me. Let me know if it solves the issue
You can refer [A Ruby library that encodes QR Codes](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode) . well explained

Comment: Hi GhostRider i put that exact code in my controller and the exact table code in my view and im still getting the following error: undefined method `modules' for nil:NilClass. i dont know why the example wont work for me are the 2 require 'rubygems' and 'rqrcode' meant to be in the gem file thanks for helping me

Comment: the gem 'rqrcode' needs to be included in Gemfile in rails application. Try this first. Set aside the application and just create a test.rb file. place the above code in it. run $gem install rqrcode to run it globally. no try $ruby test.rb. It should execute that file with no errors.

Comment: okay i did that and it seems to be creating qr code in my terminal but when i try and get the qr code onto my test.html.erb view page im getting a problem at this line <% @qr.modules.each_index do |x| %> saying "undefined method `modules' for nil:NilClass". i just want to be able to see qr code when i launch rails server

Comment: the qr code is coming as nil, add <%= @qr.inspect %> above this line and check the o/p in browser. how are you initializing qr in controller

Comment: as i see @ is missing from qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new( 'youtube.com', :size => 4, :level => :h ). it should be initialized to make it a instance variable

Comment: the code looks fine to me and it should work

Comment: check my last comment, @ is missing in before qr= line..

Comment: the missing @ in the contoller was the problem thanks a lot for your help i appreciate it